# MySQL doesn't yet support LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

```
SELECT *, 
IF(users_posts.uid IN (SELECT puid FROM post_ups WHERE  post_ups.uid = UID LIMIT 400 ) AND users_posts.uid  <> UID ,10,0)
    FROM users_posts
```

im getting this error

> This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME
>   subquery'

how can i use limit on subquery , and can i convert this to join statement , and is this query good for performance this theoretically  gona run on +Million recode ?

**UPDATE**
is this code will result the same as above ?

```
SELECT *,IF(ups.puid = t1.uid,10,0)
    FROM users_posts t1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT puid FROM post_ups WHERE  post_ups.uid = 135 ORDER BY `created_date` DESC LIMIT 400 ) AS ups ON ups.puid = t1.uid  AND t1.uid  <> 135
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by

```
`SELECT *, 
IF(users_posts.uid IN (select * from (SELECT puid FROM post_ups WHERE  post_ups.uid = UID LIMIT 400) tmp_tbl ) AND users_posts.uid  <> UID ,10,0)
    FROM users_posts`
```

Or Instead of LEFT JOIN Use INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT *,IF(ups.puid = t1.uid,10,0)
FROM users_posts t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT puid FROM post_ups WHERE  post_ups.uid = 135 ORDER BY `created_date` DESC LIMIT 400 ) AS ups ON ups.puid = t1.uid  AND t1.uid  <> 135
```